# c# DAL - Interface for business objects

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface

I have a Report Interface which has a Run method.

There are different types of reports which implement this interface and each run their own kind of report, getting data from different tables.

Each report, using its own data context, gets data which then populates Business Objects with and at the moment they are returned as an array (I would like to be able to at least return something like a list but because you have to define the list type it makes it a bit more difficult).

Reflection is then used to find out the properties of the returned data.

I hope I have explained this well enough!

Is there a better way of doing this?

By request:

```
public interface IReport
{
    int CustomerID { get; set; }

    Array Run();
}

public class BasicReport : IReport
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public virtual Array Run()
    {
        Array result = null;
        using (BasicReportsDataContext brdc = new BasicReportsDataContext())
        {
            var queryResult = from j in brdc.Jobs
                              where j.CustomerID == CustomerID
                              select new JobRecord
                              {
                                  JobNumber = j.JobNumber,
                                  CustomerName = c.CustomerName
                              };

            result = queryResult.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The other class then does a foreach over the data, and uses reflection to find out the field names and values and puts that in an xml file.

As it stands everything works - I just can't help thinking there is a better way of doing it - that perhaps my limited understanding of C# doesn't allow me to see yet.

Comment: Can you show as an example of your report interface and how it is *consumed*?

Comment: All the interface has in it really is CustomerID getter/setter and an Array Run() method - The idea was so that new Reports could be generated as part of a plugin system.

Comment: What Matthew meant was to post some code here. Your `interface` with couple of implementations and how you wish to consume it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personnally I would first ask myself if I *Really* need an interface. It would be the case if the classes implementing it are *Really* different by nature (not only by report kind).
If not, i.e all the implementing classes are basically "Reporters", then yes, there is a more convenient way to do this which is :

- Writing a parent abstract *Report*
- Having a virtual *Run* method and the *CustomerID* accessor
- inheriting your "Reporter" classes from it

Comment: That would get rid of one of my classes - any ideas on the business objects? As each report is different it will return a different business object and these are going into an array, which I then have to use reflection on to get out the properties etc - is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @m4rc Why use reflection? Each report is based on known set of business objects.